# Automatic Backup of Open Google Chrome Tabs Upon Crash

Tags: google-chrome, backup, crash, automation, tabs

Are there any chrome extensions or scripts out there that periodically saves your open tabs, even upon a crash?

If not, would it be possible to make an autoIt script to do so?

Comment: Does the "Continue Where I Left Off" setting not work for you?

Comment: @Dez Only 25% time. but that's irrelevant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just created an extension called [*Tabs Backup & Restore*](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabs-backup-%26-restore/dehocbglhkaogiljpihicakmlockmlgd) that does just that. ;)

Comment: Looks like just what I've been looking for! Can't wait to test it out

Comment: Great! Let me know how it works for you..any feedback is appreciated :)

Comment: just gave a review!

Comment: @Griffin thanks for the review!! :) I listened and I just released an update allowing an 'advanced restore' (i.e. restore individual windows or tabs from a backup). :)

Comment: Great! After using it for a week I added another suggestion  btw.

Answer (score 0):

You should try `CTRL+SHIFT+T`. It usually reopens **all** tabs that were open in previous session.

Even if you closed tabs one by one until chrome (chromium) itself was closed, you can reopen all tabs in previous session by clicking `CTRL+SHIFT+T` - although if browser didn't crash you need to use mentioned combination multiple times (open one by one tab)